# Scheduling run and restart of container instances in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-container-service, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I have a three container group running on Azure, and an additional run once container which I'm aiming to run once a day to update data on a file mount (which the server containers look at). Additionally I'm looking to then restart the containers in the group once this had updated. Is there any easy way to achieve this with the Azure stack?

Tasks seems like the right kind of thing, however I seem to only be able to mount secrets rather than standard volumes, which makes it not able to do what's required. Is there another solution I'm missing?
Thanks!

Comment: did you manage to solve this

Comment: I did not. I eventually moved to a pure VPS solution which meant I could just run a docker process whose only job was killing and restarting other containers.